# How do you create Facebook custom audiences from multiple URLs?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We need to generate custom audiences from multiple URLs but are a bit confused sorry.

---

#### 1. Pixel code

Are these the correct pixel code parameters to use?

```
fbq('init', '12345678912345567');
fbq('track', "PageView");
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
```

---

#### 2. Create audiences

And do we add the URLs when creating the Audiences in Ad Manager by using 'People who view specific web pages'?

---

#### 3. Matching URLs

And if we use the 'URL Contains' option will this work like a wildcard? i.e. entering this:

```
/segment-one/segment-two/
```

Will match the multiple URLs/paths/pages like this:

```
www.domain.com/path/segment-one/segment-two/page-one.php
www.domain.com/path/segment-one/segment-two/segment-three/page-one.php
www.domain.com/path/segment-one/segment-two/segment-three/page-two.php
```

Also, can you match partial segments like this:

```
/segment-one/segment
```

Or is it better to get specific and enter each URL one-by-one using exact match?

---

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about use of Facebook's advertising UI and not about programming for the API

Comment: Well I’m voting to keep it open because it does involves the Facebook API (note: ```fbq('track', 'ViewContent’);``` above) and Facebook help is USELESS. You’re basically forced to make a best guess and find out afterwards if you were right. I’m still not 100% sure my implementation of the pixel code is correct so if you have API knowledge, how about some pointers in the right direction?